# Placeholder only appearing after input is deleted

Tags: html, css, laravel, forms, input

I am trying to design an input field in my blade file and stumbled on something weird.

I got this Section for the input field:

```
<form class="mb-5 flex justify-left grid grid-cols-3 gap-x-20" action=" {{ route('overview') }}" method="get">

                <div class="w-full h-full text-left col-start-1 col-end-1">

                    <input placeholder="place" type="text" id="s" name="s" value=" {{ request()->get('s') }}" class="mb-2 w-full h-full bg-white bg-opacity-95 
                    rounded focus:ring-2 border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 
                    text-base outline-none text-gray-700 py-1 px-3 leading-8">
                </div>
```

When I refresh the page the placeholder doesn't appear in the input field. However, when I write something into the field and then delete this written stuff the placeholder shows up.
I am so confused :D

Comment: Remove the space from`value=" {{...` so there is _no_ value instead of a space

Comment: Nice that worked! Thank you, any idea why that impacts the placeholder attribute? @brombeer

Oh any maybe post it as an answer then I can mark it as solved! :)

Comment: Because there's a space as value (content) in the input there will be no placeholder shown. We usually don't answer questions caused by a typo, all good